# How do I change the color of a HTML element, when user taps on it?

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, webkit

My problem is so simple, that I cannot believe that there is no HTML/CSS based solution for iOS 4 and above.

I have grid of images, each subtitled with a single line of gray text. The text is bordered by lines at the top and at the bottom.

When the user *taps down* on the element (the image or the subtitle) the text and the lines should change the color to white and resets the color, when he lifts the finger again. I would even be better, if an additional line would appear at the top of the image. The whole element is encapsulated in a `div`.

I already tried to use the CSS properties `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`, `-webkit-active-link` and `:hover`, `:active` on the div or various subelements, without any success so far.

As suggested I tried this document

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highlight.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      div = document.getElementById('element');
      div.ontouchstart = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';} // on tapping
      div.ontouchend = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#000';} // on releasing
    </script>
   <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="element">
      <p>Dies ist noch ein Test.</p>
      <p>Wenn man auf <a href="#">diesen etwas laengeren Link </a> tappt, sollte was     passieren.</p>
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

with this style sheet

```
#element {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid;
    border-color:blue;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
```

But this also seems not to work.

Comment: the :hover and :active pseudo class work only on A tags...

Comment: @Leon: Absolutely not so. Hover works well on table elements and div too.

Comment: sorry, meant to add "in IE6", but not related to WebKit browsers....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div = document.getElementById('#DIV');
div.onmousedown = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = ###;} // on tapping
div.onmouseup = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = ###;} // on releasing
```

Since you're not into JS - here's the complete script for you:

```
<script>
div = document.getElementById('elem');
div.onmousedown = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';} // on tapping
div.onmouseup = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = '#000';} // on releasing
</script>
```

Put it after your element's tag.

Here something even better:

```
<script>
function changeClr( id , clr ){
    document.getElementById( id ).backgroundColor = clr;
}
</script>
```

Put the code above in the `<head>` element.
All left to do is to add to your element theese atts:

```
onmousedown='changeClr( "id" , "#f00" );' onmouseup='changeClr( "id" , "#000" );'
```

e.g. `<div id='element' onmousedown='changeClr( "element" , "#f00" );' onmouseup='changeClr( "element" , "#000" );'></div>`

That code allows you to change color of any element by adding theese atts.

Comment: Does it affect the color of the text and the line? And what exactly do you mean by ###? (Sorry, I am not into JavaScript so far)

Comment: Just take a look at the code; it affects the background color of the element you're calling - "#DIV". If you change `backgroundColor` to `color` - it will affect the text inside the "#DIV". ### means color code, e.g. `'#f00'` will give you red, as well as `#FF0000`;

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But it also doesn't work. See my question again.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough. The script tag supposed to come after your element's tag. Otherwise it won't wotk, cause the script will try to opetate an object which was not yet created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5470/discussion-between-michael-sazonov-and-tomk)

Comment: @MichaelSazonov The last solution you suggests ain't better as it does mix structure, presentation and behaviour. Better to stick with the former solution, making the javascript unobtrusive. If you want to expand the solution to include several elements it's better to use getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 2):

The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` is just what happens when a user taps something, it isn't an "on/off" state. You must use Javascript as Michael notes to effect the changes.

Comment: ah, sorry. It should change the color to gray again, if the user lifts the finder again.